# creating signatures with gd and php

Tags: php, png, gd

Does any one know good resource site that outlines how to construct user signature with use of PHP and GD library? Not that much just some sort of custom font and custom background image which is preset by the user upon uploading.

Example[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

http://scriptplayground.com/tutorials/php/Text-On-Image/

Notice how ImageTTFText() is being called multiple times: once for the text, then once for the shadow. To make your example sig image, you'll need to call ImageTTFText() for every bit of text you want to add on top of the image using coordinates and colors of your choosing.

Comment: This should not be supper hard just layer some functions together but I would agree this will take some time to style properly and to take care of all little bits/details. I guess PHP GD documentation on watermarks is pretty much what I want here. So its all good